# Finding the length of an XSTRING

Tags: abap

I have an `XSTRING` variable, but i can't find a way to find it's length (in bytes, preferrably).

It seems that when an `XSTRING` is returned/exported from a method or function module, its length is usually also exported. But in my case i only have the string itself.

Is there a way to figure out the length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you're looking for [`xstrlen( l_my_xstring )`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abendescriptive_functions_binary.htm)

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It's amazing how well this function was hiding

Comment: At least in my internet it's not hiding from Google :-)